# masked textbox , use hour format with control of max 24(hours):60(minutes)

Tags: vb.net

I use a masked textbox, and I would control the input, the problem is, I use 1 textbox and the control should on the first 2 digits with a maximum of 24 and the last 2 digits with a maximum of 60. Is there a possibility to program this?

Comment: Shouldn't it go up to `23:59` instead of `24:59`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_Validating` [event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/d6b02bd5-c773-4f4d-9601-f08c2e1668d7/) of the masked textbox.  In that example on MSDN, the extra spaces and `':'` were stripped out, and the first two digits were validated against 0-23 and the second two digits were validated against 0-59.

Comment: @ramajoud1 Yes, the link (on the word "event") goes through an example that is very close to what you describe.

Comment: @ramajoud1 Glad to hear it! If your problem is solved, please select this as an answer.